# Как создать какое-либо действие по нажатию на Тапбар перед переходом на другой контроллер?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift3

Как создать какое-либо действие по нажатию на Тапбар перед переходом на другой контроллер?Нашёл такое решение, но оно не срабатывает, принт не выводится, а просто происходит переход на др контроллер

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITabBarDelegate {
   func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
       print("ТАЙМЕР ОСТАНОВЛЕН")
   }
```

}

---

Да, добавленно не было... Добавил, но происходит крэш
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрел ваш проект.
Для достижения желаемого вам нужно сделать следующее:

1. Удалить Outlet tabBar c контроллера CounterViewController в Storyboard (в Connection Inspector)
2. Вернуть CounterViewController.swift в первоначальный вид:

   ```
   import UIKit

   class СounterViewController: UIViewController {

       override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()
       }

   }
   ```
3. Создать класс вроде MyTabBarController, наследовав его от UITabBarController:

   ```
   import UIKit

   class MyTabBarController: UITabBarController {

       override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
           print("Timer stopped")
       }

   }
   ```
4. В Storyboard TabBarController'у установить значение Class MyTabBarController

Должно заработать.

**UPDATE**

Отвечаю на ваш вопрос в комментарии по поводу выдачи Alert перед переходом на другие TabBarItems. Получилось довольно извращенное, на мой взгяд, решение, но все же, вдруг поможет:

```
import UIKit

class MyTabBarController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    var shouldSelectAnotherItems = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.delegate = self
    }

    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
        // если это первый TabBarItem (Recents)
        if viewController == self.viewControllers?[0] {
            return true
        }

        // иначе, если нажали на какой-нибудь другой TabBarItem
        if self.shouldSelectAnotherItems {
            return true
        } else {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Продолжить?", message: "Вы действительно хотите сделать ЭТО?", preferredStyle: .alert)

            let yesAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Да", style: .default) { _ in
                print("Да")
                // разрешаем переходить на другие TabBarItems
                self.shouldSelectAnotherItems = true

                // переходим на тот TabBarItem, который был нажат
                switch viewController {
                case (self.viewControllers?[1])!:
                    self.selectedIndex = 1

                case (self.viewControllers?[2])!:
                    self.selectedIndex = 2

                default:
                    self.selectedIndex = 0
                }
            }

            let noAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Нет", style: .default) { _ in
                print("Нет")
            }

            alert.addAction(yesAction)
            alert.addAction(noAction)

            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

            return false
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Работает. Еще встал такой вопрос, если перед переходом на др контроллер запускать алерт, и чтоб при его показе переход не осуществлялся, а переходил только по нажатию на согласие в алерте. Потому, что сейчас алерт показывается уже после перехода на др контроллер. Каким методом это можно задать? Спасибо

Comment: См. обновленный ответ.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Может быть, вы просто забыли указать делегата для tabBar?

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITabBarDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tabBar: UITabBar!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tabBar.delegate = self
    }

    func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
        print("ТАЙМЕР ОСТАНОВЛЕН")
    }

}
```

Comment: Да, добавленно не было... Добавил, но происходит крэш

Comment: Проверьте, правильно ли вы залинковали UI элемент… Чудя по логам, в tabBar - у вас отнюдь не UITabBar, а UITabBarItem…

Comment: В какой момент происходит крэш? Можете подробный код выложить, на GitHub, например?

Comment: Да, я UITabBarItem переименовал в UITabBar потому,что не могу найти как аутлет такой создать. Краш происходит сразу при загрузке первого контроллера, с гитом не работаю, гляньте это плиз https://yadi.sk/d/6a9Gxw45zBYuZ